# Custom validation REDCap hook

Tags: php, forms, validation, hook, redcap

I want to add a custom validation for a Textbox field in REDCap for all surveys and created forms, via a REDCap hook

How can a custom validation be added to REDCap Designer to be able to use that custom validation for Textbox fields in forms and surveys using REDCap hooks?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you can do it via a hook, but validation types can be added to REDCap via the database, meaning you have to have access to the back-end.

Here's an example of the DB record that defines a validation type:

```sql
select * from redcap_validation_types limit 1;
+-----------------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+-----------+--------------+---------+
| validation_name | validation_label                 | regex_js   | regex_php  | data_type | legacy_value | visible |
+-----------------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+-----------+--------------+---------+
| abn             | Australian Business Number (ABN) | /^\d{11}$/ | /^\d{11}$/ |           | NULL         |       1 |
+-----------------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+-----------+--------------+---------+
```

The meat of this is the two regular expressions. If you can express your custom validation as a regex, then you (provided you have database access) can insert it.

If `visible = 0` then your REDCap instance will support it if uploaded via a data dictionary, but it won't be selectable from the online designer.